# JSON to class conversion integer class name issue c#

Tags: asp.net, json, c#-4.0, asp-classic

I am getting response of JSON like this.

```
{
"serp":
    {
        "1":
        {
            "href": "href1.com",
            "url": "url1.com"
        },
        "2":
        {
            "href": "href2.com",
            "url": "url2.com"
        }
     }
  }
```

When I am trying to map with .net class it doesn't allow me to create class like
**public class 1** or **public class 2**. I want this 1 and 2 value as rank and also I want href and url value too. So how can I get this by creating class structure?

Thank in advance.

Comment: use the json serialize from http://www.newtonsoft.com/json 
get it on nuget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28874282/3501107) demonstrates a solution that might be applied to your problem using a dictionary object. You can create a class like this (just an example):

```
public class ExampleObject
{
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}
```

and use those objects in a dictionary as a value, while the key is of type Integer. This would allow to sort by the key and access the information stored in *url* and *href*.

Comment: Thank you so very much. it is working perfectly fine.