# JSON to C# Class Invalid Type Object with Inconsistent Numerical Names

Tags: c#, json

Hard to describe in words, but the API call I'm using returns JSON strings with integer names rather than something that can easily be converted to a class. You'll see in the example what I mean.

To start, I've examined the following Stackoverflow posts already, and they're helping but not giving me a complete solution to this particular JSON to C# class deserialization issue I'm having:

- [Parsing JSON to C# Object....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45404111/parsing-json-into-c-sharp-object-get-properties-dynamically)
- [How to Deserialize Objects Containing Arrays....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39461518/how-to-deserialize-objects-containing-arrays-of-values-with-a-fixed-schema-to-st/39462464#39462464)
- [Create a Strongly Typed C# Object....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34213566/create-a-strongly-typed-c-sharp-object-from-json-object-with-id-as-the-name)
- [C# JSON.NET Invalid Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28874126/c-sharp-json-net-invalid-type)

Nuts and bolts and why are the posts above not exactly helping?

Here's the JSON:

```
{    
    "related_objects": {
        "user": {
            "4243432": {
                "id": 4243432,
                "name": "Mary Poppins",
                "email": "mary@poppins.com",
                "has_pic": false,
                "pic_hash": null,
                "active_flag": false
            },
            "10658120": {
                "id": 10658120,
                "name": "Jack Spratt",
                "email": "jack@couldeatnofat.com",
                "has_pic": false,
                "pic_hash": null,
                "active_flag": true
            }
        },
        "person": {
            "425": {
                "id": 425,
                "name": "Jack L. Spratt",
                "email": [{
                        "label": "work",
                        "value": "jack@couldeatnofat.com",
                        "primary": true
                    }
                ],
                "phone": [{
                        "label": "work",
                        "value": "7045551212",
                        "primary": true
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "organization": {
            "96": {
                "id": 96,
                "name": "Leopards Domain",
                "people_count": 1,
                "owner_id": 4243432,
                "address": null,
                "cc_email": "spottedcat@kittens.com"
            },
            "220": {
                "id": 220,
                "name": "Gentle Giants",
                "people_count": 0,
                "owner_id": 10658120,
                "address": null,
                "cc_email": "wolf@hound.com"
            },
            "221": {
                "id": 221,
                "name": "Mice, Inc",
                "people_count": 0,
                "owner_id": 10658120,
                "address": null,
                "cc_email": "marvin@rodentsrus.com"
            },
            "222": {
                "id": 222,
                "name": "Footware",
                "people_count": 0,
                "owner_id": 10658120,
                "address": null,
                "cc_email": "jenny@socksandshoes.com"
            },
            "223": {
                "id": 223,
                "name": "Ignore Univ",
                "people_count": 1,
                "owner_id": 10658120,
                "address": null,
                "cc_email": "talktothehand@ignoreu.com"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I run this through my favorite [JSON to C# converter](http://json2csharp.com/#) site, I'll get something like this:

```
public class __invalid_type__4243432
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public bool has_pic { get; set; }
    public object pic_hash { get; set; }
    public bool active_flag { get; set; }
}
```

Which, I would be tempted to use, if it weren't for the fact that this call is getting something for a specific user id. If I ask for the same information for another user id, I'll get different integer returns for the name attributes.

What have I done? Well, I've read the postings noted, and I'm able to do this:

```
public class UserProperties
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string has_pic { get; set; }
    public string pic_hash { get; set; }
    public string active_flag { get; set; }
}
```

And, as a test, use this constant string:

```
  public const string USERENTRIES =
        "{ " +
        "   \"4243432\": { " +
        "       \"id\": 4243432, " +
        "       \"name\": \"Mary Poppins\", " +
        "       \"email\": \"mary@poppins.com\", " +
        "       \"has_pic\": false, " +
        "       \"pic_hash\": null, " +
        "       \"active_flag\": false " +
        "   }, " +
        "   \"10658120\": { " +
        "       \"id\": 10658120, " +
        "       \"name\": \"O. Susanna\", " +
        "       \"email\": \"O@susanna.com\", " +
        "       \"has_pic\": false, " +
        "       \"pic_hash\": null, " +
        "       \"active_flag\": true " +
        "   } " +
        "}";
```

And convert it like this, successfully:

```
Dictionary<string, UserProperties> userentries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, UserProperties>>(USERENTRIES);
```

You're probably wondering what the problem is. well, it's the fact that this dictionary construct is actually the value for the name "user" in the user/value JSON pair, as noted:

```
"user": {
    "4243432": {
        "id": 4243432,
        "name": "Mary Poppins",
        "email": "mary@poppins.com",
        "has_pic": false,
        "pic_hash": null,
        "active_flag": false
    },
    "10658120": {
        "id": 10658120,
        "name": "Jack Spratt",
        "email": "jack@couldeatnofat.com",
        "has_pic": false,
        "pic_hash": null,
        "active_flag": true
    }
}
```

What I need, in C#, I think, is something like this:

```
[JsonObject(Description = "user")]
public class User
{
    public Dictionary<string, UserProperties> UserProperties { get; set; }
}
```

Which I would used to make the conversion like so:

```
var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(USER);
```

This returns null.

This is my test JSON constant:

```
public const string USER =
    "   { " +
    "       \"user\": { " +
    "            \"4243432\": { " +
    "                \"id\": 4243432, " +
    "                \"name\": \"Mary Poppins\", " +
    "                \"email\": \"mary@poppins.com\", " +
    "                \"has_pic\": false, " +
    "                \"pic_hash\": null, " +
    "                \"active_flag\": false " +
    "            }, " +
    "            \"10658120\": { " +
    "                \"id\": 10658120, " +
    "                \"name\": \"O. Susanna\", " +
    "                \"email\": \"O@Susanna.com\", " +
    "                \"has_pic\": false, " +
    "                \"pic_hash\": null, " +
    "                \"active_flag\": true " +
    "            } " +
    "        } " +
    "   }";
```

I've tried to provide everything here if anyone wants to try it out. Of course, I'm using Newtonsoft.

I feel like I'm missing just one thing. The difference between this scenario and the others in the other postings is that the odd name/value pairs are contained within another name. In the examples, the odd name/value pairs were either not contained within anything or were themselves containers of something else.

Seems to me that the deserialization of the odd name/value pair needs to be done in some way that is apart from the deserialization of the parent class.

If this needs a specific converter built, then I'd appreciate pointers to how to do that. Likewise, if an attribute set makes it easier, that too. I noted that in one posting, the responder suggesting specifying attributes. I'd appreciate any examples of using attributes to resolve this also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're 99.99% there. Use the [JsonProperty attribute](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) to tell it that `UserProperties` is called `user` in the JSON, and `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(USER)` returns a valid `User`.

```
[JsonObject(Description = "user")]
public class User
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "user")]
    public Dictionary<string, UserProperties> UserPropererties { get; set; }
}
```

You could also just rename User.UserProperties to `User.user`, but I assume you'd rather have some control over the process.

You could make that `Dictionary<int, UserProperties>`, too. Works for me.

Comment: Wow. I can't believe how close I was. Thank you. This worked!